# Debugging a Dart WebApp with Launch target "URL" fails

Tags: dart, remote-debugging

I am using Dart Editor r22223 to debug a WebApp. If I launch the HTML file debugging works but if I open the HTML via URL (in my case that's `http://localhost:8080/samplewebappohnewebui.html`) then debugging seems not possible.

I am able the set breakpoints but the debugger does not stop at the breaktpoints.

Any hints?

[Update]
The reason for serving the HTML-file on 8080 is that the HTML file is build by Velocity...

[Update 2]
[image: SS Eclipse]
OK - I added my Dev-Configuration. In the background there is Eclipse running Jetty on 8080 but I am using Eclipse only for the Java things - not for Dart. For Dart I am using Dart-Editor.

[Update 3]
[image]

[Update 4]
Console shows message on clicks but the breakpoint does not stop the program at line 16...

[image]

Comment: Seems this issue is and already know bug: https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=3748 ...

Comment: the issue has also been fixed. could you post a screenshot of your debug configuration?

Comment: My debug configuration? In Dart-Editor? Not much to configure there?

Comment: looks like the eclipse plugin, right? And i meant this: http://postimg.org/image/h3fbdmcxz/

Comment: I don't use the eclipse plugin. It's very poor. As said above - I am using Eclipse for Java and Dart-Editor for Dart. In Eclipse I am running Jetty which acts as REST Server.

Comment: OK - I added my Debug-Config. But the server-side-config should not  affect the client side. The server produces a simple HTML-file which should be debuggable in Dart.

Comment: oh. heh. then the run configuraion of the dart editor. that's the interesting part.

Comment: OK added the run-config of the dart editor. (btw - many thanks so far for helping me!!!)

Comment: hm. can you configure your jetty to serve the page as `http://localhost:8080/JRelais.Server.REST/WebContent/samplewebappohnewebui.html`?

Comment: Ha... cool that works! I think it's more a workaround then a solution but anyway... it works :-) It has to be the exact same path for the debugger to recognize the breakpoints. Oh men! Hope they find a better solution in the future.

Comment: @MarioP Can you copy over your answer to the official "Answer section" so that I can accept and rate it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like the [issue](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=3748) isn't really fixed.

As a workaround, you can serve the page at the same URL the "normal" launch would have (the "HTML file" field in the run configuration)
In your case, this would be `http://localhost:8080/JRelais.Server.REST/WebContent/samplewebappohnewebui.html‌​`

I also filed a new [bug report](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=10427) addressing this problem, as I don't think the old one will ever be reopened.