# How to debug client side dart code in Dart editor without CORS

Tags: dart, cors, dart-editor, dartium

I have a server / client project, both written in dart. Now my server starts on port `1337` and when I run my client with the `Run in dartium`, my static files are served on port `3030` which allows me to debug my client code in the Dart editor.

The problem is that this causes [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) when using [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AJAX) calls. I have properly setup my server to accept other origins (with `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`) but, for example, cookies aren't sent along.

Now I'm wondering: is there a way to serve my files with my server (running on `1337`) and still have the possibility to debug the client side code in the dart editor?

Comment: Have you tried setting the `withCredentials` property on `HttpRequest` to `true` - e.g `HttpRequest.getString(url, withCredentials:true)`?

Comment: Thanks Zdeslav, that worked (after setting the right `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` and `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials`). Still wondering if there is a concrete answer to my question.

Comment: I am not sure I understand. It seems that you can execute the client side code. I would expect that you can debug it too. What happens exactly if you set a breakpoint somewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My understanding is that you can debug, but the real problem is that you don't get the expected data back from the server due to missing cookies.

Standard CORS requests do not send or set any cookies by default.

In order to include cookies as a part of the request, besides setting up the server, you need to specify [`withCredentials`](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_html/HttpRequest.html#request) property, e.g.:

```
HttpRequest.getString(url, withCredentials:true)...
```

You will also need to setup server to provide `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials` header.

EDIT: it seems that additional issue is that you don't want to have 2 servers, each serving different part of app.

In that case, you can configure DartEditor to launch the URL, instead of files. Go to `Run > Manage Launches` and add create a new Dartium or Dart2JS launch with specified URL and source directory.

Another option is to select `Run > Remote Connection` and attach to a running instance of browser or Dart VM.

Caveat: I haven't tried these options, so I can't tell [how stable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16358773/debugging-a-dart-webapp-with-launch-target-url-fails) [they are](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=3748).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It helped me continue to work for now. But eventually I want to serve the files myself, as in production, and still be able to debug in the dart editor.

Comment: You mean, something like attaching to Dartium?

Comment: Thanks... exactly what I wanted. Cheers